# What's wrong with this integration?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, indefinite-integrals

$\int t^2 p(x,t) dt$ , where $p(x,t)$ is the joint density function
$t^2 > 0$ $\forall t$ and $p(x,t) > 0$ everywhere, thus the answer must greater than $0$.
However, using the integration by parts, I cancel out everything. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this integration by parts?

$$\int t^2 p(x,t) dt  = t^2\cdot p(x) - 2\cdot \int tp(x) dt = t^2\cdot p(x) - t^2\cdot p(x) = 0$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I suggest you review the formula for integration by parts. You will automatically figure out "what's wrong" . Also give us more information about $p(x,t)$ so that maybe someone could actually give you the proper way to integrate.